# I cannot add in my ArrayList [Android]

Tags: java, android, arraylist

In my class I created a `variable` named `taskArray` and initialized it in my `onCreate` like this

```
 public class ActivityOne extends Activity {
 ArrayList<WorkTask> taskArray = null;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {   
    taskArray = new ArrayList<WorkTask>();

  final GetTasks getTasks = new GetTasks();
        getTasks.execute();

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if ( getTasks.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING ) {
                    getTasks.cancel(true);
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityOne.this, "Connection Timeout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, 60000 );
 }
```

And then in my `AsyncTask` in `doInBackground` I'm adding the data on the `branchesArray` but It doesn't add. Before it is working correctly, but now it doesn't. My code looks like this

```
 public final class GetTasks extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Employee> {
   protected Employee doInBackground(Void... params) {

     try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL_STRING);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            str =  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        try{
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
            JSONObject data = jsonObject.getJSONObject("DATA");

            //Employee info
            empObj = new Employee();

            empObj.setId(data.getInt("id"));
            empObj.setName(data.getString("name").toString());

            JSONArray jArray = data.getJSONArray("worktask");

            for (int i = 0, count = jArray.length(); i < count; i++) {
                JSONObject jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                WorkTask workTask = new WorkTask();

                workTask.setId(jObj.getInt("id"));
                workTask.setTaskName(jObj.getInt("task_name"));

                taskArray.add(workTask);
            }

        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return empObj;
    }
```

Here is my model `WorkTask`

```
public class WorkTask implements Serializable {
 private int id;
 private String taskName;

  public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

 public int getTaskName() {
    return taskName;
}

 public void setTaskName(int taskName) {
    this.taskName = taskName;
}
```

Comment: The reason it's not working correctly is that your code is wrong.  If you want more specific information about what's wrong with your code, please provide more specific information about how this isn't working.

Comment: @ajb I updated my code. When debugging it, it doesn't go to `taskArray.add()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a stupid mistake here, my other values is getting data from `jObj` that should be from `empObj` that's why it always go to the `catch`. I already fixed it now and working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you write more information about your code.

It can occurred by `count` is zero that means `jArray` is empty list.

Frist, you check your json data about `worktask`.

Comment: checking my `jArray` it has 3 array. I have a data but it doesn't add in the `ArrayList`

Comment: @mori so you not execute `AsyncTask`? If you have data in `jArray` and execute that operation, `taskArray` must have elements.

Comment: I execute it. Please check my updated code.